# How to wrap text around a logo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

[image: Logo]

Hey guys, how can I wrap a text that says "Association of Medical Students in Bulgaria" around the top of this logo, and around its bottom "Professional and Research Exchange". I have Photoshop CC 2015, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Type Tool selected (T), click on the "Create Warped Text" icon at the top of your screen.  It looks like a T with a curved line under it:

[image]

Select "Arc" and adjust your settings

[image]

A more in-depth and complicated way of doing this is by placing the text on a path.

- Create a path in the shape that you want your text to be
- Select the Type Tool again and hover over your path until the icon changes from the default [T] looking one to a T with an s-curve running through it
- Click when the icon changes and begin typing

To adjust the text's position on the path, use the Path Selection Tool (A) to move various points around the path

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The only problem is that this "curved" option on the top appears grey to me, meaning it doesn't allow me to click on it... Any idea why?

Comment: @Sai I can't tell why it isn't available for you, but I added another method to try